# installing libv8 8.4.255.0 with Ruby 2.6.10 and Apple M1 chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am working on an Rails (Ruby 2.6.10) app that needs libv8 but fails repeatedly when trying to `bundle install`. The error is the following :

```
Error: Command 'vpython third_party/depot_tools/update_depot_tools_toggle.py --disable' returned non-zero exit status 1 in
/Users/jackel/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor
Running: gclient root
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "name": "v8",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "managed": False,
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
```

I am a bit lost as to how to fix as most answers online seem to be directed at intel / x86_64 chips. Any idea on how to get this working correctly?

Comment: Are you using a ruby manager like RVM or rbenv? Have you tried to install libv8 by itself? `gem install libv8` What version of Bundler?

Comment: As is your question is impossible to answer. Why are you installing in .asdf? How did you install Ruby. What does your gemfile look like?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed libv8 on my M1 Macbook Air with:

```
gem install libv8
Fetching libv8-8.4.255.0-x86_64-darwin-20.gem
Successfully installed libv8-8.4.255.0-x86_64-darwin-20
1 gem installed
```

I'm using Ruby 2.6.6 in this directory with rbenv as my ruby manager. As you can also see it is building the x86 version. That is because I run the terminal in Rosetta mode so it emulates the old x86 architecture until all the libraries I need catch up. To set that you go to Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal, right click on terminal and "get info" (command i) and check the box for Rosetta.

Comment: interesting - I was hoping to not use Rosetta but think it might be best solution. Strangely, when running `gem install libv8`, it goes through `Building native extensions. This could take a while...` rather than just downloading compiled gem. Are you using any `bundle config` values?

Comment: It almost always does that for me if I have never installed a gem before. As for avoiding Rosetta, I don't see any reason to avoid it for a Rails app. You can always make a copy of the Terminal.app and set that one to Rosetta so you have both. As for Rails apps, it is going to do a `bundle install` on any target system so it will get built for that system anyway. I run all mine in Rosetta and have been pushing to Heroku and have never had a problem.

Comment: And unless you are planning on only running your stuff on Apple Silicon, probably better to know that it works in an x86 environment, since that is what almost all the commercial systems are running it against.